# Can a c# console application with no input field be SQL Injected

Tags: c#, sql, console, code-injection

I have a console application that targets a file and performs SQL queries and other things.. Basically a server. However, it does not have a text input field of any kid. COuld it still be injected?

Comment: What exactly is a console application that "targets" a Shockwave client?

Answer (score 2):

Yes.

If it operates on attacker-controllable data from any source, it can still be attacked.

For example:

- If it accepts URLs, attackers can add or modify malicious querystring parameters
- If it operates on existing data in the database, attackers can try to set that data through other applications

Answer (score 0):

Only if it's reading command line arguments or interpreting other external inputs (external files) — otherwise, no.

Comment: If the command line program reads a file and uses that to construct a query, compromise the file and you can inject SQL (just an example).

Comment: " or interpreting other external inputs (external files) " seems to pretty much cover it.

Answer (score 0):

If you are not using parameterized queries, there's still potential for SQL injection for any dynamically built SQL query.

If you build it dynamically, that means the data comes from *somewhere*.  Perhaps a file, a system call, command line parameters, or an internet call.  If the source of input can be compromised, SQL injection is possible.

Comment: If either can be compromised, SQL injection is possible.

Answer (score 0):

Yes - if anything is transmitted over a network, it is susceptible to a man in the middle attack.  If everything is contained locally on one machine, the likelihood is a lot less; however, it is still very possible.

Comment: He's asking about SQL injection, not MITM.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how you use SQL query in your console application, if you SQL query is not taking any input from command line input or file input or any input, then there is no injection.